# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una captura de pantalla de un determinado tamaño con WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium

Estoy intentando tomar una captura de pantalla de una determinada región de la pantalla o con un determinado tamaño con selenium.
El tamaño que trato de imprimir es de 392 x 294 píxeles.

Este es el código que manejo:

```
from Selenium import webdriver

DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER)
driver.get('localhost:8080')
screenshot = driver.save_screenshot('my_screenshot.png')
driver.quit()
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer una captura de pantalla de un tamaño específico, ya sea con selenium o con algún otro método?
De antemano agradezco mucho su ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con un tamaño específico? ¿a que el archivo tenga cierto tamaño? o ¿Que el navegador se ajuste a un tamaño de dispositivo específico?

Comment: A que la captura tenga cierto tamaño específico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por si a alguien le llegase a servir, utilicé `pillow`. Es una librería que te permite editar imágenes desde python. Para instalarlo ejecuta desde la consola o terminal (en caso de usar linux) `pip install pillow` o `python -m pip install pillow`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

#Definimos la ruta donde se ubica la herramienta chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

#Definimos la url de donde queremos capturar la pantalla 
driver.get('https://es.stackoverflow.com/')

#Creamos una variable que define qué tipo de extensión tendrá la imagen, en este caso png
png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png() 

im = Image.open(BytesIO(png))
#im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) Serán las coordenadas de posicionamiento de la imagen
im = im.crop((546, 138, 930, 553))

#Guardamos la captura en una ruta
im.save(r'C:\Users\youna\Pictures\Captura.png')
```

Adjunto una imagen ilustrativa para aquellos que no puedan posicionar la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]